# Python Tkinter project structure for nested pages

Tags: python, tkinter

I have one Python project running which has 4 main pages and each main page contains 2 to 3 sub pages within them. it's a class-based project that follows [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/15022289) approach for changing the pages.

Currently the project looks like this

```
my_app/
|-- main.py
|-- constants.py
|-- fonts/
|-- images/
|-- pages1.py # each page contains class-based sub-pages, and parent page act as controller
|-- pages2.py
|-- pages3.py
|-- pages4.py
...
```

All the pages have different classes for their sub-pages, and it is working fine.
Now I want to split these pages and sub-pages into separate files as each page file's code is too lengthy and hard to maintain.

To do the same, I have structured my project in the following manner, **but getting errors with `imports`**

```
my_app/
|-- main.py
|-- constants.py
|-- base_methods.py
|-- database.db
|-- fonts/
|   |-- font1.ttf
|   |-- font2.ttf
|-- images/
|   |-- img1.jpg
|   |-- img2.jpg
|-- pages/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- page1/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- sub_page1.py
|   |   |-- sub_page2.py
|   |   |-- sub_page3.py
...
```

When I try to import my `constants.py` or `base_methods.py` file in `sub_pages1.py`, I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'` and `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Tried following import patterns

```
from ..constants import *
from constants import *
from ... import constants
```

Comment: You could add your parent dir to path: **sys.path.insert(0, parentdir)**

Comment: Does it have to be in every file?

Answer (score 0):

Import issues might be caused by wrong working directory.
try navigating to the proper working directory using cd in the terminal and see if it imports

Comment: Tried, Was running the code for parent directory itself

Comment: @lazy_coder
might be stupid, buy have you tried just 'import constants' ?

Comment: yes sir, did that too